# How to use locate in cygwin?

Tags: linux, cygwin, locate

I'm trying to use `locate` to find files, but I'm not getting anything back from the program.  It can't even find files that are in the current directory.  How do I make `locate` work?

Comment: use sudo updatedb ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In essence, you have to run `updatedb` first, as this builds the database that `locate` uses.
Simply do `updatedb --localpaths=c:/` as a first shot solution.

See this blog post for a bunch of good tips, including how to setup up `updatedb` via cygwin `cron`:
https://web.archive.org/web/20061114000822/www.weiqigao.com/blog/2006/08/14/ten_steps_to_higher_cygwin_productivity.html  (updated link to archive.org)

Google `cygwin updatedb` for a relevant post if you are having trouble with paths that include spaces. I am not getting any trouble (other than permission denied) on WinXP Pro, but other platforms may require this.

Comment: The blogpost has a new address, http://webpages.charter.net/weiqigao/2006/08/14/ten_steps_to_higher_cygwin_productivity.html

Comment: I've found that a simple invocation of updatedb won't work in Cygwin, as the default options (or --localpaths=c:/) will lead it into following links into infinite loops. I think this is because certain types of Windows 7 links don't appear as symbolic links to Cygwin, so it can't skip them (as the default -follow behavior is, counter-intuitively, supposed to)

Comment: The blogpost is unreachable.It would be better to inline its advice here.

Comment: Thanks @reinierpost, fixed the link.  The post is too long to inline, IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

To use `locate` you need to run `updatedb` first.

Answer (score -1):

I think the command you want is `find`

Do `man find` to see the syntax and options

The locate command runs against a pre-built database of filenames

Comment: Yes, locate runs against a pre-built database.  Why does that mean the OP wants find instead?

Comment: Find will at least do the job that is being requested if locate is not present or for what-ever reason not functioning. More slowly, as it won't have the pre-prepared data to search, but it will work and the results are more likely to be properly uptodate and complete (updatedb may have been configured to exclude some parts of the filesystem).